# Dynamically reading select XML content into Hashtable using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, hashtable

I am writing Powershell code that does the following

1. Reads the contents of XML files in a directory
2. For each XML file in the directory
   a. Print selected contents of the XML files (not all the nodes)
   b. Save the selected content into a hashtable named $securities

I am unable to do 2(b)

Here is my code:

```
$directory = 'C:\Scripts\Results'
[hashtable]$securities = @{}
$CUSIP=$NULL
$Int_Rate=$NULL
$Issue_Date=$NULL
$Maturity_Date=$NULL

foreach ($i in (Get-ChildItem $directory -Name)){
    write-host $i
    [xml]$xml = [xml](Get-Content $directory\$i)
    $CUSIP = $xml.AuctionData.AuctionAnnouncement.CUSIP
    Write-Host CUSIP $CUSIP 
    $Int_Rate = $xml.AuctionData.AuctionResults.InterestRate
    Write-Host Interest Rate $Int_Rate 
    $Issue_Date = $xml.AuctionData.AuctionAnnouncement.IssueDate
    Write-Host Issue Date $Issue_Date 
    $Maturity_Date = $xml.AuctionData.AuctionAnnouncement.MaturityDate
    Write-Host Maturity Date $Maturity_Date 
    Write-Host `n
    $securities.add=($i,$CUSIP,$Int_Rate,$Issue_Date,$Maturity_Date)

}

$securities
```

And this is my output for $securities

Name          Value
----          -----
CUSIP        {Jul_2012.xml, 912828TE0, 0.125, 2012-07-31...}

This is not the value I was looking for. The value I am looking for is something like

Jan_2011.xml
CUSIP 912828PP9
Interest Rate 1.125
Issue Date 2011-01-31
Maturity Date 2021-01-15

Jan_2012.xml
CUSIP 912828SA9
Interest Rate 0.125
Issue Date 2012-01-31
Maturity Date 2022-01-15

Jul_2010.xml
CUSIP 912828NM8
Interest Rate 1.250
Issue Date 2010-07-15
Maturity Date 2020-07-15

Jul_2011.xml
CUSIP 912828QV5
Interest Rate 0.625
Issue Date 2011-07-29
Maturity Date 2021-07-15

Jul_2012.xml
CUSIP 912828TE0
Interest Rate 0.125
Issue Date 2012-07-31
Maturity Date 2022-07-15

Please point me in the right direction.

EDIT

Hi David

I tried

```
 $securities.add($i, [pscustomobject]@{'CUSIP'=$CUSIP;'Int_Rate'=$Int_Rate;'Issue_Date'=$Issue_Date;'Maturity_Date'=$Maturity_Date})
```

And got the following output for $securities

```
Name Value                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                 
Jul_2012.xml                   @{CUSIP=912828TE0; Int_Rate=0.125; Issue_Date=2012-07-31; Maturity_Date=2022-07-15}                   
Jul_2011.xml                   @{CUSIP=912828QV5; Int_Rate=0.625; Issue_Date=2011-07-29; Maturity_Date=2021-07-15}                   
Jul_2010.xml                   @{CUSIP=912828NM8; Int_Rate=1.250; Issue_Date=2010-07-15; Maturity_Date=2020-07-15}                   
Jan_2012.xml                   @{CUSIP=912828SA9; Int_Rate=0.125; Issue_Date=2012-01-31; Maturity_Date=2022-01-15}                   
Jan_2011.xml                   @{CUSIP=912828PP9; Int_Rate=1.125; Issue_Date=2011-01-31; Maturity_Date=2021-01-15}
```

But I don't know how to reference it.

For instance, when I try to get value for

```
$securities.Jul_2012.xml('CUSIP')
```

I get error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Scripts\treasury_holdings.ps1:24 char:1
+ $securities.Jul_2012.xml('CUSIP')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Instead of

```
912828TE0
```

EDIT:

Thank you David.

To help others, here is the latest code:

```
$directory = 'C:\Scripts\Results'
[hashtable]$securities = @{}
$CUSIP=$NULL
$Int_Rate=$NULL
$Issue_Date=$NULL
$Maturity_Date=$NULL

foreach ($i in (Get-ChildItem $directory -Name)){
    write-host $i
    [xml]$xml = [xml](Get-Content $directory\$i)
    $CUSIP = $xml.AuctionData.AuctionAnnouncement.CUSIP        
    $Int_Rate = $xml.AuctionData.AuctionResults.InterestRate     
    $Issue_Date = $xml.AuctionData.AuctionAnnouncement.IssueDate    
    $Maturity_Date = $xml.AuctionData.AuctionAnnouncement.MaturityDate            
    $securities.add($i, [pscustomobject]@{'CUSIP'=$CUSIP;'Int_Rate'=$Int_Rate;'Issue_Date'=$Issue_Date;'Maturity_Date'=$Maturity_Date})
    Write-Host CUSIP $securities[$i].CUSIP
    Write-Host Interest Rate $securities[$i].Int_Rate
    Write-Host Issue Date $securities[$i].Issue_Date
    Write-Host Maturity Date $securities[$i].Maturity_Date
    Write-Host `n
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling the following:

```
$securities.add=($i,$CUSIP,$Int_Rate,$Issue_Date,$Maturity_Date)
```

The problem is with the equals sign there. What that actually does is insert a record with a  key "add" with the rest of the values as the value. What you really want is to add a record with the key $i and a value of everything else. Try creating a [[pscustomobject]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscustomobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the rest of the values, and adding them to the hashtable, like so:

```
$securities.add($i, [pscustomobject]@{'CUSIP'=$CUSIP;'Int Rate'=$Int_Rate;'Issue Date'=$Issue_Date';'Maturity Date'=$Maturity_Date})
```

EDIT:
Try doing either of the following:

```
($securities.Jul_2012.xml).CUSIP
```

or

```
$securities['Jul_2012.xml'].CUSIP
```